# Blender script works differently in/out of for loop

Tags: python, scripting, armature, transforms, makehuman

My goal is to automatically load a MakeHuman model and apply a CMU mocap file on it. This works perfectly fine in Python (using interactive window), but when I try to do it as a batch script, I get a weird behavior.

Specifically, moving the character so that her toe aligns with origin works differently depending on whether I use it as a script or interactively. Since we can't access bone's world coordinates directly, first I have to create an empty object at the same location and get this objects coordinates instead.

In the script version (using a for loop), the character gets a completely different translation and it rotates a bit downwards, which does not happen when I run the steps by hand, individually.

[image: what it should be (when commands are entered individually)]

[image: what the script version produces]

I managed to locate the source of the issue through going over each line, and it seems to be this section:

```
  matrix_final = pose_bone.id_data.matrix_world * pose_bone.matrix
```

The rest of the script:

```
import bpy
import os 

model_path = '/home/aarslan/prj/data/makehhuman_models/showcase/'
bvh_path = '/home/aarslan/Desktop/cmu_bvh_dump/'

models = ['1']
bvhs = ['10_01']

for m in models:
   for b in bvhs:
      this_m = os.path.join(model_path, m, m+'.mhx')
      this_b = os.path.join(bvh_path, b+'.bvh')
      bpy.ops.import_scene.makehuman_mhx(filepath=this_m)
      bpy.ops.mcp.load_and_retarget(filepath=this_b)
      #SHIFT THE CHARACTER TO ORIGIN
      bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_current= 1
      toe_b=bpy.context.object.data.bones['toe.L']
      toe_b.select=True
      bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = toe_b
      pose_bone = context.active_pose_bone
      # we can get the object from the pose bone
      bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
      matrix_final = pose_bone.id_data.matrix_world * pose_bone.matrix
      # now we can view the matrix by applying it to an object
      obj_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Test", None)
      bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj_empty)
      obj_empty.matrix_world = matrix_final
      diff_loc = obj_empty.location
      bpy.ops.transform.translate(value = diff_loc*-1)
      bpy.ops.mcp.shift_bone()
      # END ORIGIN SHIFT
```

Any ideas how can I make sure the script runs the way I want it? I looked into the modal() functions explanation but not sure if it'll solve the issue.
Thanks

---

EDIT:

I can safely say that the primary issue is `pose_bone.matrix` . It gives two different matrices depending on how it is called (i.e. in or outside the for loop). This is a completely unexpected behavior to me and it looks like a bug.

Comment: Do you use FK or IK settings? Could you provide test files by uploading to http://pasteall.org/blend/ . To change the position you should move the root bone rather than the toe. My toe bone is named toe.FK.L. You could easily have forgotten to select the bone layer (e.g. made interactive but not added to the script) `bpy.context.object.data.layers[i]=True`

Comment: Thanks @stacker. The IK/FK point is a good lead. My toe is called toe.L, and I haven't changed anything about IK/FK. But when the transformation is applied, the T pose is changed in such a way that the character leans against her toe. But after your comment I did try to select the 'hip' and transform that, but I got even worse results (that indicate an IK/FK confusion). Here's the new script: http://pasteall.org/blend/30067 . The model: https://dropbox.brown.edu/download.php?hash=dea0225e 
The mocap data as an example: https://dropbox.brown.edu/download.php?hash=f23fb035

Comment: @stacker I made an edit in the question. It looks like the bone's matrix changes depending on how it is retrieved. That seems like the primary issue (that I still couldn't understand) but I do think that there's an IK/FK problem going on during the actual translation.

Comment: I now assembled all your parts and got `AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.mcp.load_and_retarget" error, could not be found.` Ok this seems to be part of make walk. Look into   http://makehuman.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/makehuman/tools/blender/makewalk/retarget.py the 3rd comment block shows how the matrices depend on each other,  have you also tried to create a new character with makehuman, the rigs of the chars I created look very different (and so do the layers). It seems to be a rather large project when you couldn't find more infos or tutorials.

Comment: @stacker, you'd need to make sure the blender tools that accompany makehuman (specifically "makewalk") are installed in add-ons. That should solve the error. I discovered that retrieving "matrix_basis" of bones in/out of for loop gives completely different results and I don't know how to solve that. In line 430 of "makewalk/loop.py", you can discover that the matrices are completely different depending on how you call the bpy.ops.mcp.shift_bone() function (that lets you move the character after you apply the mocap). And yes, different characters (same armature template) give the same issue.